Sorting xml with Groovy
My question is related to the answer given by Sean Reilly to the question:
Use Groovy to Sort XML File
When I replace there
rootNode.children().sort(true) {it.attribute('name')}

with
rootNode.Person.sort(true) {it.attribute('name')}

the Person nodes aren't sorted by their name attribute anymore. Why is that? When I compare rootNode.children() with rootNode.Person for equality true is returned. I am working with Groovy version 2.4.21.
I expect that in both cases the Person nodes are sorted.

children() gives you back the list of children in the root node. Product returns a new list containing the children whose tag matches Product. Sorting this new list doesn't affect the original list of children

@tim_yates: But the original xml is modifiable through the rootNode.Person list. For example rootNode.Person[0].@first = 'hello' adds an attribute to the first Person node. I am wondering why sorting this list has no effect on the xml.

Person[0] is the first element with the tag Person. But when you're sorting, you're sorting a list that is a copy. It is not the list used to store all the children. So the copied list is sorted, but this has no effect on the root node

@jimmy_blue, for example xml: <root><a/><b/><a/></root>. then xml.a will return a copy of all children with tag name a. when you sort a copy it's not affecting the real children of the root node. However you can replace all children of the node with a new list.

@tim_yates & daggett: Thanks for your clarification.

You'd need to do one of the following

Remove all Person tags, then add them back:

def people = rootNode.Person.sort(true) {it.@name}
rootNode.children().findAll { it.name() == "Person" }.replaceNode {}

people.each { n -> rootNode.appendNode( n ) }


Sort all children at once:

rootNode.children().sort(true) { a,b -> 
   if( a.name() == b.name() && a.name() == 'Person' )
      return a.@name.compareTo( b.@name )
   else if( a.name() == 'Person' ) return -1
   else if( b.name() == 'Person') return 1
   else return 0
}

Essentially sorting all Person nodes ahead of all other nodes, and if both are Person nodes then comparing their @name attributes.
